# Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 dock HDMI/DisplayPort 19.10

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, thunderbolt

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Tablet Gen 3 connected to a Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock 40AF. On the dock connections, everything (Ethernet, USB, Charging) works, but only HDMI and DisplayPort connections will not.

I have tried the standard tricks of enabling and disabling the Thunderbolt access in the Gnome UI and I have also been following [this tutorial](http://juho.tykkala.fi/Lenovo-Thunderbolt-3-dock-Linux). Strang thing is that `boltctl` command will not yield any output. I have been looking for log files, etc. but not found anything that would give me further information.

I cannot (and also do not want to) disable the BIOS security features.

Any further input what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thunderbolt 3 is a tunnelling protocol that can transport PCIe and DisplayPort data. A bit confusingly, Thunderbolt is one of the "alternate modes" of the USB type C port. Besides Thunderbolt and USB 3, the port itself can also directly act as DisplayPort and HDMI port (amongst others). See the [schema](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/10248/tb3-02.png) from anandtech.

When used with a Thunderbolt device, the PCIe tunnels are only created once the device is authorized, unless security is disabled. This is done via `bolt` and the kernel. But the DisplayPort streams do **not** require authorization and should always work. The same is true for DisplayPort alternate mode in case a DisplayPort device is directly connected to the USB Type C.

That you see no output via `boltctl` and the type specifier for the dock (40AF) makes me believe that you have indeed the *[ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/accessory/docks/thinkpad-hybrid-usb-c-with-usb-a-dock/40af/downloads/DS502119)* dock, which is **not** a Thunderbolt dock. In that case the DisplayPort/HDMI of the dock use [DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) and thus likely need an additional [driver](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu).

NB: Logs for bolt can easily be obtained via `journalctl -b -u bolt` but I am pretty sure bolt is not in the mix here.

Comment: thanks. Indeed your observation was correct. The Hybrid Dock ist *not* a Thunderbold dock.... Will install the displaylink driver.

Answer (score 2):

Following [these](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkPad-Hybrid-USB-C-with-USB-A-Dock-for-linux/m-p/4406052/highlight/true#M2280) steps have helped getting 40AF dock to work with my T490 with Ubuntu.

> > By [sbalko](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1881770)
>
> I followed these steps to get the Lenovo USB-C docking station support
>   two external monitors (Apple 27' cinema display with miniDP/F to DP/M
>   adapter and a simple 1080p HDMI monitor) with my E480 (running Ubuntu
>   18.04):
>
> - Use a Windows PC to upgrade the docking station firmware (see
>     https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/pd500180) BIOS: turn off
>     the Secure Boot option
> - Download and install the DisplayLink drivers
>     for Ubuntu (see https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)
> - Follow the troubleshooting procedure for the latest Intel iGPU Linux drivers
>     (see
>     https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recen...)
> - Reboot
>
> While neither of these steps is exactly hard to perform, I wish
>   Lenovo would get their act together re supporting Linux.